# Freemember error message

Tags: freemember

I installed Freemember as an addon module for Expression Engine. I'm still getting this error when I try to set up registration form.

```
Error

In order to use the encryption class requires that you set an encryption key in your config file.
```

I'm using EE 2.7.3 and PHP Version 5.3.2 . I have added this to my config.php file

```
$config['encryption_key'] = "l49YGsxdrq3VcNJdxTWQcaKKhBKREfNb7nbGSxOxBPMnHumuzCVkwa9xoTFHkBq";
```

So why I am getting this error message?

Thanks you,
randy

Comment: Which version of FreeMember are you running?

Comment: Did you find the solution to this? If so, it would be helpful to come back and post the answer for future visitors.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure it is not being overwritten in the config.php file. At the bottom of the config file, the encryption key is declared as blank, so make sure the key is entered there, or below these lines of code

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Encryption Key
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If you use the Encryption class or the Sessions class with encryption
| enabled you MUST set an encryption key.  See the user guide for info.
|
*/
$config['encryption_key'] = '';
```